# Type 'Observable<never> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Can anyOne help me to solve this problem? I'm trying to make it like this https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp

ng --version

Angular CLI: 11.0.5

Node: 14.9.0

OS: win32 x64

dotnet --version

5.0.101

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    @Injectable()
    
    export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (error.status == 401) {
                            return throwError(error.statusText);
                        }
                        const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                        if (applicationError) {
                            console.log(applicationError);
                            return throwError(applicationError);
                        }
    
                        const serverError = error.error;
                        let modalStateErrors = '';
                        if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object') {
                            for (const key in serverError) {
                                if (serverError[key]) {
                                    modalStateErrors += serverError[key] = '\n';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error');
                    }
                })
            );
        }
    
    }
    
    export const ErrorInterceptorProvider = {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
        multi: true
    };
```

Comment: Your tags are `C#` and `AngularJS`.  It looks like your code is neither.  It looks like `Typescript` and `Angular` (no JS).  If you want the right people looking at your code, you will want to tag it with the correct tags

Comment: You have no default return statement in your `catchError`-handler so it returns either `Observable<never>` or `undefined`.